# Restrict Google Datastudio View to > 5 rows

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

How can I configure a Google Datastudio dashboard to only show aggregate data if there are 5 or more data rows?

To explain: I seek to offer a Google Datastudio dashboard to explore aggregate data (e.g., happiness index) with multiple filters (e.g., gender, age, location). I also seek to assure privacy for the underlying data sources (e.g., Peter, Mary, John). Certain filter configurations could result in the queried response data to be N=1 and so enable inference or re-identification of the actual respondent. How can such scenario be prevented through settings or by defining a SQL syntax that only operates if N => 5?

The data is provided by Google BigQuery.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> How can such scenario be prevented through settings or by defining a SQL syntax that only operates if N => 5?

Below is simple example that shows how to accomplish this via SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT num
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 20)) num
), result AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE num < 9
)
SELECT *
FROM result 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) >= 5 FROM result)
```

Brief explanation:

- `project.dataset.table` just mimics you data "stored in BigQuery"
- result CTE - mimics your "aggregate data" whatever it might be
- finally WHERE clause in last SELECT statement does the "magic"

You can test/play with above by changing `WHERE num < 4` in result CTE mimicking different number of rows in output of your aggregation